# Master Detail Relationship Detail value is not showing

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Hi i am writing a visual force whose code is

```
 <apex:page id="pageId" controller="FieldSetDemonstration">  
<apex:form id="formId">  
    <apex:pageblock id="pbId">  
        <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" id="pbsIs">  
            <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="f">  
                <apex:outputLabel value="{!merch[f]}">  
            </apex:outputLabel></apex:repeat>  
        </apex:pageblocksection>  
    </apex:pageblock>  
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

and controller code is 
public class FieldSetDemonstration {

```
public Resource__c merch { get; set; }

public FieldSetDemonstration() {
    this.merch = getMerchandise();
}

public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
    return SObjectType.Resource__c.FieldSets.Hello2.getFields();
}

private Resource__c getMerchandise() {
    String query = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : this.getFields()) {
        query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
    }
    query += 'Id  FROM Resource__c LIMIT 1';
    System.debug('Hello world debug log');
   Resource__c res= Database.query(query);
   Object re=res.Resource_Position__r.Name;
```

System.debug('Hello World Debug log'+''+res);
System.debug('Hello World1 '+query);
  return res;
    }
}

and System Log values are

12:28:55.052 (52125000)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|Hello World Debug logResource__c:{Name=Hello Bro, OwnerId=00590000001V6loAAC, Id=a04900000023JI7AAM}

12:28:55.052 (52157000)|USER_DEBUG|[23]|DEBUG|Hello World1 SELECT Resource_Position__r.CreatedById, Resource_Position__c, Name, Owner.Email, Resource_Position_*r.Name, Id  FROM Resource*_c LIMIT 1

and there is a master detail relationship between Resource__c and Resource_Position__c
Hello2 in code is a fieldset
which contain following fields

Resource Position > Resource Position Name

Resource Position

Resource Name

the problem i am facing instead of showing value of all three fields
1.Resource Position>Resource Position Name
2.Resource Position
3.Resource Name
its showing value of only Resource Name
no value for

Resource Position>Resource Position Name

Resource Position

but i associate a Resource_Position_*c object  with Resource*_c object why its not showing the value of these two fields can any one please help in solving this problem.ur help is highly appreciable

if i add one more Field in fieldset hello2 Owner ID>E-mail then its showing correct email address of owner in visualforce page only problem is coming from this customobject's field name can any one please tell why its not giving value for Resource_Position__c.name fiels

Comment: Turn on debug logs and check if the relationships are actually queried (`System.debug(query)`)? That way you'll know whether it's a display issue or query has to be constructed in different way.

Comment: @eyescream i turned on debug logs and the result of query is
01:10:59:064 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [7]|res|{"serId":1,"value":{"Name":"Hello Bro","Owner":{"serId":2,"value":{"Email":"developercontest@gma (6 more) ...","Id":"00590000001V6loAAC"}},"OwnerId":"00590000001V6loAAC","Id":"a04900000023JI7AAM"}}|0x7f6902ef
and the query is 
SELECT Resource_Position__r.CreatedById, Resource_Position__c, Name, Owner.Email, Resource_Position__r.Name, Id  FROM Resource__c LIMIT 1

Comment: so its not a display issue i think its query issue and probably this query is correct.if its wrong then please suggest what should be query

Comment: @eyescream can you please tell what is (6 more) in Email":"developercontest@gma (6 more)this (6 more) in debug log is it il.com 6 characters or some thing else??please tell

Comment: Yes, I think it's full email (I don't like the "developer console" exactly because of this stuff... Use raw view of the debug log or "oldschool" - turn on debug logging in setup?

Comment: I've asked for `System.debug(query)` (the string, not results of `Database.query` ;) But it seems to be querying through relation to `Owner.Id` and `Owner.Email`... Really weird, I'll need to look at it in detail

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20527/discussion-between-ritesh-mehandiratta-and-eyescream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<apex:outputLabel value="{!merch[f]}">` To `<apex:outputLabel value="{!merch[f.fieldPath]}">`